# drupal password reset not functioning AND email not sending for reset

Tags: drupal

I am not a drupal guy, and would hate to have to jump in and step through a login to figure out the password reset, but I CANNOT SEEM TO RESET ADMIN PASSWORD.  I have searched on this.  I thought this good link would be helpful:

http://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/different-ways-reset-drupal-admin-password

so I tried the query suggested:

```
UPDATE users SET name='admin', pass='$S$Drl0vgZ9yuU9uc4JyaTMHxMPriC7q/PsOUOx52fCrVQSTpI/Tu4x' WHERE uid = 1
```

where that specific hash is supposed to represent the password 'drupal' - well, it doesn't work.

Furthermore, though I have changed the user.email field to my email, when I try and get a reset link, nothing arrives - and I've tried several emails.

I'm thinking maybe I have an older version?  How may I determine this?  I'm at the point where I'm ready to do a complete new drupal install, just to snip out the working portion of the login.  It shouldn't have to be that difficult!  I appreciate your help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do this.

You can execute drush uli, this will generate a one time login link. By default it provides one-time login link for administrator.

If you execute "drush uli some-username", this will generate one time login link for that user.

OR

excecute "drush help user-password" (Re)Set the password for the user account with the specified name.

Examples: drush user-password someuser --password="correct horse battery" Set the password for the username someuser. @see xkcd.com/936

Arguments: someuser The name of the account to modify.

Options: --password= The new password for the account. Required.

Aliases: upwd

-- To do this, you need to ssh into the root directory of you drupal installation.